# Why is my Modal Bottom Sheet not blocking the main screen?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, bottom-sheet

From documentation, I read that the Modal Bottom Sheet should block the main screen and place a tint over it. I thought all that needed to be done was to extend `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and it would work. Is there a property that is not being set?

Bottom sheet class:

```
class BottomTimeSheet: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var bottomSheetLayout: ConstraintLayout
    private lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<ConstraintLayout>
    private lateinit var bottomSheetCloseBtn: MaterialButton


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false)

        bottomSheetCloseBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_btn1)
        bottomSheetLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_layout)
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetLayout)
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object: BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback(){
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
            }

            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                Log.d(TAG, "newState: $newState")
            }

        })

        bottomSheetCloseBtn.setOnClickListener {
            hideBottomTimeSheet()
        }

        return view
    }



    fun showBottomTimeSheet(){
        if(bottomSheetBehavior.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED){
            bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        }
    }

    fun hideBottomTimeSheet(){
        if(bottomSheetBehavior.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED){
            bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
        }
    }


    companion object {
        val TAG = BottomTimeSheet::class.java.toString()
    }

}
```

bottom_sheet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a bottom sheet"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_sheet_text"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_sheet_btn1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

The bottom sheet slides up, but you can see there is not tint nor blocking on the main screen. The buttons on main screen are still clickable.

**Edit:**
I am instantiating and invoking the bottom sheet like this

```
private lateinit var bottomTimeSheet: BottomTimeSheet

bottomTimeSheet = BottomTimeSheet

bottomTimeSheet.showBottomTimeSheet()
```

element in main_activity.xml:

```
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:name="com.ds.base.fragments.BottomTimeSheet"
       tools:layout="@layout/bottom_sheet"/>
```

Comment: How are you starting your `BottomTimeSheet`? By calling `show()` on it? Or with a regular `FragmentTransaction`? It should be the former. Also, `BottomSheetDialogFragment` provides its own `CoordinatorLayout` setup. You only need to provide your content, and you don't need to specify the `BottomSheetBehavior` on it.

Comment: I made an edit showing how I am starting it. I am starting it, by using the class function. Inside that function I set the state of the sheet.

Comment: No, I mean, how are you launchIng that `Fragment`? That is, how are you getting it on-screen? With a `FragmentTransaction`? Or do you possibly have a `<fragment>` element in a layout? Or are you calling `show()` on it?

Comment: Sorry yes it is a `<fragment>` element in the `main_actvity.xml`

Comment: OK, that's your problem, then. You're treating it like a regular `Fragment`, but it's a `DialogFragment`. To get it to act like a `Dialog` – and, therefore, be modal – remove that `<fragment>`, instantiate it in code – `bottomTimeSheet = BottomTimeSheet()` – then call `show()` on it – `bottomTimeSheet.show(supportFragmentManager, "whatever_tag_string_you_want")` – and `dismiss()` to hide it. Note that it will dismiss itself if you touch outside of the content. And, as mentioned above, you don't provide you're own `CoordinatorLayout` or `Behavior`, so get rid of those, as well.

Comment: Thanks, that shows modal bottom sheet but it is not using my layout. 

       <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet"/>

        </FrameLayout>

Comment: Sorry I dont know why it was not formatting my code correctly in the comment above. The above element is inside my `main_activity.xml` I need it there so it will be constrained to bottom right of the main screen.

Comment: Nothing for the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` should be in the `Activity`'s layout. This is a completely separate thing. A `Dialog` is a separate window entirely; like a mini-`Activity`. It uses its own separate layout, so remove that from `main_activity`. It is being inflated in `onCreateView()` in your `BottomTimeSheet` class, and that's the only place you should have it.